# Can't delete OU from AD, IsCriticalSystemObject attribute TRUE - cannot change

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016

I recently took over a contract for a customer where the previous IT apparently did a half-ass job of migrating from SBS Server to Server 2016.

In AD there's an OU called MyBusiness which has two subfolders: **SBSComputers** and **SBSUsers**. I've moved all of the computers out of SBSComputers to the top level Computers OU and the same for SBSUsers. The folders are empty.

Now I'm trying to delete the two OU's but they have the **isCriticalSystemObject** attribute set as **TRUE**. When I try to set the attribute to FALSE I get the following error:

> Operation failed. Error code: 0x2077 
>   Illegal modify operation. Some aspect of the modification is not permitted. 
>   00002077: SvcErr: DSID-03190CD8, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0

Thanks for any help guys, pulling my hair out with this one!

Comment: "I recently took over a contract for a customer where the previous IT apparently did a **half-ass job** of migrating from SBS Server to Server 2016" - bad-mouthing begets bad-mouthing. There's value and no honor in doing it.

Comment: Oh, they definitely did a half-ass job but it wasn't for this issue. There was ghost DC's, dual DHCP's and all kinds of bad DNS records. Definitely was a half-ass job.

Comment: You may have inherited a mess, but I don't see the point in bad-mouthing your predecessor. Clean it up, leave it better than you found it, and take pride in a job well done. There's no point in knocking other people.

Comment: Will take your advice as food for thought, Joe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Now I'm trying to delete the two OU's but they have the
>   isCriticalSystemObject attribute set as TRUE.

This is because those are the default locations for new computer and user objects in an SBS domain. The fact that you've removed SBS doesn't change the fact that this was set automatically by the SBS install when the domain was created. If you want to delete those OU's then you'll need to change the default location for new computer and user objects.

http://www.expta.com/2009/03/changing-default-users-and-computers.html

Comment: This fix worked perfectly. Thanks so much Joe!

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 5):

You have to (re)set the default location for new user/computer objects aded to the domani to another container/ou.

Set the OU/CN fpr new **computers**

```
C:\> redircmp OU=NewComputerOU,DC=domain,dc=tld
```

Set the OU/CN fpr new **users**

```
C:\> redirusr OU=NeueBenutzerOU,DC=domain,dc=tld
```

After that change was replicated, the old OUs can be deleted.